# Analyse number of possible keepalive_requests from the client side

Tags: apache, nginx, tcp, performance-testing, keep-alive

I'd like to figure out the value of 'keepalive_requests' for a given 'Nginx' or 'Apache' server from the client side. The default for 'Nginx' is 100 (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) but I'd like to analyse this for www.example.com where I don't have access to the config.

Obviously I could start a Wireshark and do it manually. I was hoping on some sort of easy shell (e.g. 'wget' like) command.

Comment: Some discussion here might help - [link]http://serverfault.com/questions/447855/how-filter-only-keep-alive-packet-with-tcpdump

Answer (score 1):

From client side, I use ab test, wireshark, and an editor like notepad++ to count number of http requests in a socket.

First I use apache ab test to send request, something as bellow:

ab -n 100 -c 100 http://www.example.com/index.php

Before execution, start my wireshark, and set the display filter:

ip.dst ==  && tcp.port == 80 && !http && tcp.flags.fin==1

After the ab test finished, the result list of wireshark shows the total sockets used during the requests. Right click one packet, and click follow TCP stream, the opened windows shows all the message send and receive in this socket.

If the last FIN direction was sent by remote nginx server, which was influenced by the value of keepalive_requests. We can copy the all requests in this TCP connection into the notepad++, search for the key word and then count the requests in this socket. the number presents the value of keepalive_requests setting in the remote nginx server.

BTW, I wish a better solution, my solution is not so good.